# c/c++ and objective c ios

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

I would like to return the height of the iPhone status bar from a c/c++ function.

I did this in an mm file:

```
int ios_status_bar_height_platform()
{
    return [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
}
```

It claims that it doesn't know what UIApplication is.

How do I include and how do I know what to inlude and how do you mix c/c++ and objective c?

*edit*: I know c and c++ but nothing of objective-c, i am working in x-code

Comment: Hardcoding is not always bad :D the status bar is always 20 ^^.

Comment: i was told its 40 on retina? how sure are you :D

Comment: the hardcoded values are multiplied by 2 on the retina screen by the system. The method you are trying to call we also return 20 on a retina device

Comment: An important misconception here many people seem to have. This is not a C++ function. This is a C function and Objective-C is a superset of C, so C functions are part of the language. You can call C++ functions from Objective-C, but C++ is an entierly different language so you need to use .mm suffix which tells your compiler you are compiling Objective-C++ code. However a .m file may contain regular C functions as C is part of Objective-C. Remember C and C++ are two different languages. They are not fully compatible. C and Objective-C are fully compatible on the other hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you'll find

> Framework:    /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework

therefore

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

should help. For more information, see ["Including Frameworks in Your Project"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html) in the "Framework Programming Guide".

Comment: thank you this does help me find what i need to include

Comment: build succeeded, the fact i just accessed objective-c stuff from a c function in an mm file blows my mind but whatever

Comment: @user3345413 you should be able to mix C, C++ and Objective-C whichever way you like. Google Objective-C++ for examples. :)